# boost solr3 relevancy score if field exists

Tags: solr

I'm a solr newbie. I have been tasked to boost solr doc's relevancy score if a field exists. We are on solr3.4. Upgrading is not an option. We use lucene parser, so dismax is not an option. My other option is to add a field to the solr index, which indicates if the field exists and then boost the relevancy on the exists field.

Is there another option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would give a try to the following syntax:

```
email_address:*^2000000
```

This boosts all documents that have any value in the field 'email_address'. According to [Lucene syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) documentation both colon (**:**) and boost (**^**) operators are supported by Lucene, so this should work there.